# How to retrieve all target file descriptors in epoll before exit and correctly release all allocated memory?

Tags: c, epoll

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_ctl.2.html

```
int epoll_ctl(int epfd, int op, int fd, struct epoll_event *event);
```

I would like to know a method to help release memory associated with a `fd` which is monitored by `epoll`.

Here is one example:

```
struct MyStructOne
{
  int fd;
  // some data fields
};

struct MyStructTwo
{
  int fd;
  // some data fields
};

struct epoll_event event;
struct epoll_event events[MAX_EVENTS];
int epoll_fd = epoll_create1(0);

// Register the fd_one descriptor with epoll.
struct MyStructOne* data_one = malloc(sizeof(struct MyStructOne));
data_one.fd = fd_one
event.events = EPOLLIN;
event.data.ptr = data_one;
epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd_one, &event);

// Register the fd_two descriptor with epoll.
struct MyStructTwo* data_two = malloc(sizeof(struct MyStructTwo));
data_one.fd = fd_two
event.events = EPOLLIN;
event.data.ptr = data_two;
epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd_two, &event);

while(true)
{
  int num_events = epoll_wait(epoll_fd, events, MAX_EVENTS, -1);
  if (num_events < 0) {
      perror("epoll_wait");
      break;
  }
  // do something here
}

// Now we need to release all allocated memory but how?
```

**Question**> In above example, when we experience some issues within the `while` loop, the code will break the infinite `while-loop` and exit. Right before exit, I would like to know I can correctly deallocate memory associated with each monitored `fd` (i.e. `fd_one` and `fd_two`).

Thank you

Comment: Is it really just the memory allocation you do care about? If so, why? Deallocating memory in "preparation" of process termination is like giving a house a redecoration before taking to it with a wrecking ball. All resources held by a process will be released on exit, anyway, and in a more efficient manner than manually going over each and every resource.

Comment: You are right, I should not really care about the memory deallocation if the application will exit anyway. The OP is regarding how to deallocate the memory while the program will continue to run.

Answer (score 0):

Free malloc. Close file descriptors.

```
close(epoll_fd);
free(data_two);
free(data_one);
close(fd_one);
close(fd_two);
```

Comment: This doesn't help. Since I don't have a global struct that keeps recording of all these pointers.

Comment: I do not understand how a global struct that "keeps recording" of "pointers" is related to the problem. With the presented code, the variables are in scope at point of `Now we need to release all allocated memory but how?`.